# Previous version debug signature and Update android application

Tags: android, debugging, signature

I want to update my application. I changed the version code but when I try to install that application it won't succeed.

This error message is shown:

> An existing package by the same name with a conflicting signature is
>   already installed

How to get previous version debug signature and set it in Android studio? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two parameters that remain in your `build.gradle` file of your app.

```
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"
```

> android:versionCode — An integer value that represents the version of the application code, relative to other versions.
>
> android:versionName — A string value that represents the release version of the application code, as it should be shown to users.

Please refer [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html) documentation to know more about this.

Also you can get the VersionName and VersionCode programatically, in this way --

```
PackageInfo pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(this.getPackageName(), 0);
String versionName = pInfo.versionName;
int versionCode = pInfo.versionCode;
```

EDITED:

Please refer [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) documentation to create a `debug.keystore` file.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, but i have a problem with signing.How to get previous version debug signature and set it in Android studio?

Comment: You are talking about the keystore file, right? Have you created a Debug Keystore file?

Comment: Yeah. I published my app in market with debug signature. now i want update that. i increased version code but when installed that, this message showed: An existing package by the same name with a conflicting signature is already installed.

Comment: Did you change your VersionCode parameter in your `build.gradle` when you have created an upgraded version of the app? It says -- *You can set the value to any integer you want, however you should make sure that each successive release of your application uses a greater value.*

Comment: Yes.I changed it. How to set these?
Keystore name: "debug.keystore"
Keystore password: "android"
Key alias: "androiddebugkey"
Key password: "android"
CN: "CN=Android Debug,O=Android,C=US"

Comment: I have provided a documentation that will help you to create a `debug.keystore` file. Please check the edited section of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to ensure that your phone doesn't have the same application already installed whilst you are trying to install the same application's new APK.

So before installing the application, follow the following steps: 1. Go to Settings of your phone and look for an option that lists all applications in your phone and try to find whether the application that you are trying to install is already listed. If it is, then uninstall it from there. 2. Usually uninstalling by following step 1 removes the application from your phone however, if you are using a tablet, sometimes Android still keeps the APK file in the downloaded directory. So come out of settings and find out "All files" folder. Look for your app's APK in "downloaded" folder inside "All files" folder and remove it from there too.

Once you have deleted your app by following the above steps then you can go ahead and install your app. Hopefully you won't see "an existing package by the same name with a conflicting signature is already installed" error message.